# Connection issue from latest .Net MongoDb.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I created a MongoLab sandbox database. I connected with MongoChef and it works fine.

I installed MongoDB.Driver 2.2.2 through Nuget.

I made some simple C# demo code, but just don't make it work.

The connection string was copied straight from MongoChef where it definitely works!

When trying the same with a local Mongo instance I get the same behaviour. But when trying with driver version 2.1.1 it works locally and with MongoLab! Is the internal connection behaviour changed in some way in 2.2?

```
    const string connectionString = "mongodb://user:password@ds047095.mongolab.com:47095/dbname";

    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    var db = client.GetDatabase("dbname");
    var skills = db.GetCollection<Skill>("skill");
    skills.InsertOne(new Skill {SkillName = "TEST"});
```

This is the exception thrown:

A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "127.0.0.1:27017" }", EndPoint: "127.0.0.1:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument MongoDB.Bson.RawBsonDocument.Materialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBinaryReaderSettings)'.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__47.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.d__42.MoveNext()" }] }.

Comment: When desperately trying everything I also switched to different driver version. To my surprise everything works again when going back to version 2.1.1. But the succeeding version 2.2.0 does NOT work. I still have no explanation as to why.

Comment: The same problem also occurs when connection to local MongoDb instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the possible solution: check version of following packages: MongoDB.Driver, MongoDB.Driver.Core, MongoDB.Bson in all your projects in solution. Maybe some packages have different versions, then update them to latest version. Also update your MongoDB to latest version. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might very well be right that this is related to server version. I know upgraded my client driver to 2.2.3 again and upgraded my local server installation to 3.2.4. That combination worked fine. The problem was that I during development have used MongoLab Sandbox version that for a long time only allowed version 2.x. Now they have upgraded Sandbox to 3.0 so it actually works there too!

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issues while I was doing some POC with .net core, docker and mongo DB. Turns out to be the mongodb connection string issues. After replacing the "localhost" with the IP, the issue got resolved. But this was working fine with IIS.

**Fix**

version: '3.4'

services:

reverseproxy_mongodemoapp: 
    image: rnd/reverseproxy_mongodemoapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/reverseproxy/Docker_reverseproxy
    volumes:
      - ./var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    ports:
      - 5500:5500
    networks:
      - mongodemoappdockernat
    restart: always

mongodemoapp:
    image: rnd/mongodemoapp:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/mongodemoapp/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - reverseproxy_mongodemoapp
    networks:
      - mongodemoappdockernat
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development
      - BooksCollectionName=${APP_MONGODB_COLLECTION:-Books}
      **- ConnectionString=${APP_MONGODB_CONNECTION:-mongodb://192.168.0.105:27017/}**
      - DatabaseName=${APP_MONGODB:-BookStore}

networks:
  mongodemoappdockernat:
    driver: bridge

Answer (score 0):

Try  connection string without database name:

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://user:password@ds047095.mongolab.com:47095";
```

Comment: Sorry, but no, it makes no difference. Did you actually try this with latest driver? The one that I use now is 2.2.3. The error is identical. I tried with several databases on several locations with same result. For test purposes I can do with driver 2.1.1. But this is potentially bad if we never are able to upgrade driver. Can you really trust this in production?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used the driver in a web project and it was all working well. I then refactored those into another project, but forgot to remove the MongoDB library references in the web project. It took a while, but worked after removing the dll references from the web project. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have the same problem with free hosting for MongoDB from mlab.com. Mongo compass connect succesfully. Driver version 2.7.2, latest version from available for VisualStudio. 
Problem solved by changing hosting provider to MondoBD.Atlas.